# How to convert selected sections of a html to docx

Tags: pandoc

I routinely convert html to docx with this simple command:

pandoc -s input.html -o output.docx

I would like to use the same approach to only convert parts of the html file. The html file comprises of various sections inside the `<body>` tag including `<table>`, `<div>` and `<span>`. I only want to convert the content of `<span>` sections. Is the approach to create a template file, if so, how do I format it?

Or is there a better way of achieving this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to keep most of the HTML document unchanged. In that case, use an HTML parser in your preferred programming language and then pass the relevant snippets to pandoc.

Comment: I have Python installed, but I'm not exactly a coder. Can you recommend a Parser that might do the job. Happy with cmd stuff. Thanks.